# How do I override the "On" methods in the ASP.NET Core gRPC service application hosted by the Windows service?

Tags: c#

There is an application created from the `ASP.NET Core gRPC Service` template, and placed in a Windows service using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` package. But how can I override `OnStart`, `OnStop`, `OnSessionChange` methods?

Current `Program.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;
using RControl.Server.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
});

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5233");

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGrpcService<ServerService>();
app.Run();
```

Comment: The API design of `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` is radically different to the old `System.ServiceProcess` - instead of overriding `OnStart`/`OnStop` you now implement `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService` (which is _not_ specific to Windows Services) which has a single method: `ExecuteAsync` which is a single _cancellable_ method that represents the lifetime of a service between Start and Stop - there's a guide available here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/creating-a-windows-service-with-c-net5/

Comment: _That said_, you don't need to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`: the old `ServiceBase` class is available if you want to use the old API design - reference `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` instead.

Comment: You haven't shown us your `ServerService` class.

Comment: @Dai, `ServerService` contains the logic of the gRPC service (implementation of methods generated from the `proto` file), it is irrelevant to the question